# Multi-PC powerbrick

Tags: power-supply, power

I have few mini PCs around, all of them have 19V input. Each comes with a dedicated 65W power brick. I want to power them all from the same large PSU, like 500 W Meanwell or something. Should I add some diodes to the output or is it fine if they all share the same output?